# mp4 html5 video on Samsung Tizen Smart TV web browser not working

Tags: .htaccess, html5-video, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, samsung-browser

This is the situation:

`<video controls><source src="10053.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>`

Not working, won't load video on Samsung browser (Smart TV Q80T model of 2020)

BUT, if you rename the file to .sd.mp4 it works:

`<video controls><source src="10053.sd.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>`
It works!

Anyone knows how to fix this without rename all .mp4 files?
Any knows how to add a an entry to .htaccess in order to set on url .../[0-9+].hd.mp4 and look into the system .../[0-9+].mp4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by a wrong .htaccess policy trying to block hotlink or play in a wrong referer.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://URL.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)\.mp4$ https://URL/ [R,NC]
</FilesMatch>
```

Removing or commenting `RewriteRule` fixes it.